# How to stock a value in a session php

Tags: php

I have a problem with PHP. On my website, you can choose between three langauges (French, English and German).

I can easily change the language but I when go on an other page, it doesn't remember what language I choose.

This is the beginning of my index.php page :

```
<?php
session_start();
require("decide-lang.php");
$_SESSION = $lang;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <?php include('include/head.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Header-->
    <?php include('include/header.php'); ?>
```

And this is the code of my change the language:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
} elseif(isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
} else {
    //default language of the navigator
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2);
}
//script d'origine
if ($lang=='fr') {           
    include('lang/fr-lang.php'); 
} elseif ($lang=='en') {      
    include('lang/en-lang.php'); 
} elseif ($lang=='de') {    
    include('lang/de-lang.php'); 
} 

//fin du script d'origine
//définition de la durée du cookie (1 an)
$expire = 365*24*3600; 
// //enregistrement du cookie au nom de lang
// setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + $expire);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, the core of get and set language it's here:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['lang']))
  $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang']; //GET value from chosen lang

if(!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
  $_SESSION['lang'] = 'fr'; //default case

require_once 'lang/' . $_SESSION['lang'] . '-lang.php'; //include file dinamically
```

Comment: It's perfect. Thank you :)